# How to concate array elements on value basis in php

Tags: php

I have array like this :

```
Array
(
    [attribute] => Array
        (
            [0] => sku
            [1] => sku
            [2] => attribute_set_id
        )

    [value] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1, 2, 3
            [1] => 3, 4
            [2] => 4
        )

)
```

In the above array attributes are like keys and values are values .I want to  concatenate same key values like here  required `sku` will be `(1,2,3,4)`. I can join them by combine array.The result array will be like

```
array('sku'=>'1,2,3,4',attribute_set_id=>'4');
```

The above array will be dynamic.

Comment: will there always be 2 'sku' arrays ?

Comment: thanks it will not always be two sku keys but could be not only sku but other attributes key too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a builtin function to do the job, you have to write the algorithm yourself, something like

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array['attribute'] as $i => $key)
{
    $value = str_replace(' ', '', $array['value'][$i]);
    if (isset($result[$key]))
        $result[$key] = implode(',', array_unique(array_merge(explode(',', $result[$key]), explode(',', $value))));
    else
        $result[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Would this not make it 1,2,3,3,4?

Comment: Thanks your code solve my problem.Thanks alot.but there is little issue it not generate unique values.

Comment: Oops, didn't see that. Edited. It does take the beauty out of the solution quite a bit. ;) You might want to add another `array_walk('trim', ...)` or `str_replace(' ', '', ...)` to the values.

Comment: I think array_walk or custom function will be bitter where I can  send the values and explode it and than apply array_unique function on it. what you think ?

Comment: What do you mean? I suggested the `array_walk()` as one possibilities to get rid of the spaces.

Comment: Sorry but above code still showing me Array
(
    [sku] => 1, 2, 3,3, 4
    [attribute_set_id] => 4
) as a result array.

Comment: I added a `str_replace()` to remove the spaces. If your values can contain spaces, you need to use the `array_map()` method.

Comment: Thanks but i made it using foreach($result as $key => $val)
{
  $arr_t = explode(",",$val);
  $new_var = array_unique(array_filter(array_map('trim',$arr_t)));
  $variable = implode(",",$new_var);
 
} code.thanks for such forum